# jquery datepicker insert dayid to all days within <td> attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to add dayid to all `<td>`

[image]

for example:

```
<td class=" " data-year="2022" data-month="8" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
 <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a>
</td>
```

would be like

```
<td class=" " data-year="2022" data-month="8" dayid="22" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
  <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a>
</td>

<td class=" " data-year="2022" data-month="8" dayid="23" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
  <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a>
</td> ... and so on
```

is this possible in jquery? I started writing this

```
$('td')
 .filter('[data-year="2022"]')
 .filter('[data-month="08"]')
 .find('a') // find all Anchors in this filtered result
 .attrib('dayid', '');
```

but don't think it can work as I don't want to hardcode the year & month, and can't get the value of each  to set the attribute

Comment: OK, I am curious as to why you need to do this.  If by chance you run something like this method it goes away: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "destroy" );` and you would have to re-do it.  There may be another way to obtain your objective here.

Comment: Why `.find('a') // find all Anchors in this filtered result` if as you said you want the `td` to have the new attribute (as your example shows)

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the `a` and assign it's `text()` to the containing `td`

```js
$('td[data-year] a').each(function(i, o) {
  $(o).closest('td').attr('dayid', $(o).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=" " data-year="2022" data-month="8" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=" " data-year="2022" data-month="8" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked but here is one way to get all the days of the current calendar using the `data-date` attributes the calendar uses.

```js
let $datepicker = $('#datepicker');
$datepicker.datepicker({
  duration: 1 // really fast for our purpose here
});

// creates a datepicker element by showing and hiding so we can then walk through
$datepicker.datepicker("show").datepicker("hide");
// back to normal speed for usability
$datepicker.datepicker( "option", "duration", "normal");
$sd =$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find("[data-date]");
console.log("We have:",$sd.length," Dates in the month, here they are:");
$sd.each(function(){console.log($(this).data("date"));});
```

```css
.picker-container {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.picker-container>tbody {
  display: flex;
}

.picker-day {
  border: solid green 1px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="picker-container">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div>
```